# EXCEL VBA format textbox while writing or when tab is pressed

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

so i'm almost finished with my code, just missing one thing, the user will have to introduce 12 numbers, example "123456789123" and the outcome is 123-456.789-123, i managed to get the format when printing to excel sheet, but i wanted something that could give me that format in the moment as it's easier to spot any error of input. Example the user puts 123456789123 on the textbox and when tabing to another box it formats. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible (!) - but for clarity can you share your code?

Comment: I work in a company and i can't share the code policy of company, for my bad i can only express my ideia

Comment: Can you obfuscate the code? Certainly you can share things like `Sub myMacro // With Worksheets("My Sheet") // ...`  If not, you may not have much luck here as we typically need an [mcve].

Comment: Read this: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/33032-text-box-input-mask.html

Comment: I managed to get it work with one type of format but the one i want seems to not work.  "###-###.###-###" or "@@@-@@@.@@@-@@@"

Comment: I have this so far...

Comment: Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    ~~> This avoids refiring of the event
    If boolSkip = True Then
        boolSkip = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ~~> Get current cursor postion
    CursorPosition = TextBox2.SelStart
    boolSkip = True

    ~~> Format the text
    
    TextBox2.Text = Format(TextBox2.Text, "###-###.###-###")
    
    

    ~~> Re-position the cursor
    If InStr(1, TextBox2.Text, ".") - 1 > 0 Then _
    TextBox2.SelStart = InStr(1, TextBox2.Text, ".") - 1
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 3 And TextBox1.Text Like "###" = True Then     
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "-"
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 7 And TextBox1.Text Like "###-###" = True Then 
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "."
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 11 And TextBox1.Text Like "###-###.###" = True Then 
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "-"
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 15 Then TextBox1.Text = Left(TextBox1.Text, 15)

End Sub
```